# Renaming file messing up with the file

Tags: java, android, file, android-contentresolver

I am trying to rename a file and android studio. But when I try to rename the file then the readable, writable and hidden property of file get set to false. and last modified date of the file changes to "01/01/1970 05:30 AM".

```
//minSdkVersion 19

private ArrayList<FileData> getMusic(Context context) {
    ArrayList<FileData> fileData = new ArrayList<>();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor externalCursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

    while (Objects.requireNonNull(externalCursor).moveToNext()) {
        System.out.println(externalCursor.getString(0));
        fileData.add(getFileData(context, new File(externalCursor.getString(0))));
    }

    sortByDate(fileData);

    return groupDateWise(fileData);
}
```

Renaming File

```
File renameFile = new File(file.getParent(), editText.getText().toString().trim());
boolean success = file.renameTo(renameFile);
```

Before Rename

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmhUI.png)

After Rename

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtUCi.png)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access the `java.nio` packages you can set those flags explicitly

```
boolean success = file.renameTo(renameFile);

if (success) {
   renameFile.setReadable(true);
   renameFile.setWritable(true);
}
```

---

*JavaDoc* to the rescue!

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent.

I would suggest you to **not** use `renameTo`.
Instead look for `Files#move` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)))

```
move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```

Example:

```
Files.move(file.getParent().toPath(), renameFile.toPath() /* Or simply Paths.get("your-path") */);
```

Comment: The minimum SDK version I am using is 19. And this is solution requires SDK 26